# C# Forms -- Resizing DataGridView removes the Scroll Bar

Tags: c#, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a form which contains a DataGridView. When the grid is populated it has around 2500 rows. Because of this a ScrollBar is placed on the right to navigate. This is default.

I have just programmed my form to resize the DGV. When the user resizez now, the ScrollBar dissapears. You can still navigate with the mouse wheel.

I want to get the scroll bar back.

Does any one know why this happens?

```
for (int i = 0; i < languageTabs.TabCount; i++)
        {
            Control[] ctrls = languageTabs.TabPages[i].Controls.Find(languageTabs.TabPages[i].Name + "Grid", true);
            DataGridView dgv = ctrls[0] as DataGridView;
            dgv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width - 40, this.Height - 125);
            dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None; // doesnt seem to do anything
            dgv.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both; // doesnt seem to do anything
        }
```

Abve is the rezizing loop for all tabs and DGV's.

Comment: Have you tried 'ScrollBars.Auto' ?

Comment: @Shai Both, Horizontal, None and vertical are the only properties I can apply to the Scrollbar in dgv.

Comment: try maintaining the width property - don't change it and see what happens

Comment: @Shai I just saw a post somewhere that says I need to set a minimum width for each column. Will try this now and report back if its correct.

Comment: yep I read that too. Something about Scrollbars vanishing because the control does not have enough width.

Comment: @Shai -- Even tried making all columns frozen (saw this in another post) still didnt help.

Comment: `this.Width` you are setting all datagrid view's width relative to current. **this** keyword refers to your current form. In new Size() write some fixed value and then check size of gridview..   i do not the size of your form.. but you are maintaining this stuff in wrong way..

Answer (score 1):

```
            // resize the dgv and columns
            for (int i = 0; i < languageTabs.TabCount; i++)
            {
                Control[] ctrls = languageTabs.TabPages[i].Controls.Find(languageTabs.TabPages[i].Name + "Grid", true);
                DataGridView dgv = ctrls[0] as DataGridView;

                dgv.SetBounds(14, 14, this.Width - 70, this.Height - 150);
            }
```

The problem was the ammont I was sizing by ( -70 , -150). Before it was too little so the scroll bar was hidden to the right.